# how to change LUIS subcription key in .Bot file which is encrypted in Enterprise bot v4

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

i am developing a bot with V4 Enterprise template as bot is working fine now but i want to change subscription Key in .bot file due to .bot file is encrypted im not able to change how can i encrypt just subscription key in .bot file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref [Manage bots using CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tools?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to install a utility

```
npm install -g msbot
```

Ref [Microsoft/botbuilder-tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/bot-file-encryption.md)
 use the msbot utility to decrypt

```
msbot secret -b my.bot --secret OLDSECRET --clear
```

Then if required, encrypt the file, this will generate new secret, so you will also have to change secrets in configuration files and/or Azure settings.

```
msbot secret -b my.bot -n
```